Understanding the Relationship between $L^2$, Fourier Coefficients, and Absolute Continuity
In a recent lecture, it was stated that $A:= \{f \in L^2(-\pi,\pi) \mid |k| \hat f_k \in l^2\} = \{f \in AC[-\pi,\pi] \mid f' \in L^2(-\pi,\pi)\} := B$.
It was named a Sobolev space.
At first glance, this seemed reasonable, but upon further consideration, I believe there are some issues with this statement.
The space $L^2(-\pi,\pi)$ consists of equivalence classes of functions, where two functions are considered equivalent if they differ only on a set of measure zero. However, the space of absolutely continuous functions ($AC[-\pi,\pi]$) does not consist of equivalence classes, as it requires specific pointwise properties. Therefore, the equality $A=B$ seems problematic unless further clarification is provided.
If we consider $A$ as all functions however, that are in $L^2$ with $|k| \hat f_k \in l^2$, then consider the zero function on $(-\pi,\pi)$ with a value of $1$ at a single point (i.e. at $x=0$).
This function belongs to $A$ because modifying $f$ on a set of measure zero does not change its Fourier coefficients.
However, it does not belong to $B$, as it is not even continuous, let alone absolutely continuous.
I suspect that the intended meaning is something along these lines:
For every equivalence class of functions in $A$, there exists a (possibly unique) representative $f\in AC[-\pi,\pi]$ such that $f'$ exists almost everywhere and $f' \in L^2(-\pi,\pi)$.
Could someone clarify how the equality $A=B$ is meant in this context? Am I missing some subtle assumption or interpretation that resolves these issues?

The intended meaning that you suspect is exactly right. What is still problematic and not really mentioned is that you only get the $2\pi$ periodic functions in $AC[-\pi,\pi]$.

@PhoemueX Thank you, $AC[-\pi,\pi]$ is the set of all periodic functions in our setting. I forgot to mention that. Is the absolutely continuous function in the equivalence class unique?

If two continuous functions are equal amost everywhere (wrt Lebesgue measure) then they are equal everywhere. Therefore an equivalence class can have at most one continuous representant.

@jd27 oh yes of course, thank you
